# How do I use _mime_types in ZSH

Tags: function, zsh

I'd like to know the MIME type of some files. Under Zsh, I see the following:

```bash
% functions + | grep -i mime
_mime_types
_zsh-mime-handler
```

Now, how do I use `_mime_types` function on the prompt?

Comment: Does [this](https://zsh.zle.lc/zsh-mime-functions.html) help?